# PyMongo 3 and ServerSelectionTimeoutError while getting data from Mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, docker, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

This seems like an old solved problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-961) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710427/pymongo-and-multiprocessing-serverselectiontimeouterror) but Still I am getting this error.I create my db on Docker.And It worked only one time.Before this, I re-created db, did "connect =false",added wait, downgraded pymongo, did previous solutions etc. I stuck.

Python 3.8.0, Pymongo 3.9.0

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

client = MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.1.100:27017/',
                      username='admin',
                      password='psw',
                      authSource='myappdb',
                      authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1',
                      connect=False)

db = client['myappdb']
serverStatusResult=db.command("serverStatus")
pprint(serverStatusResult)
```

and I am getting ServerSelectionTimeoutError

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\eclipse2019-workspace\exdjango\exdjango__init__.py",
>   line 12, in 
>                           serverStatusResult=db.command("serverStatus")
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py",
>   line 610, in command
>                           with self.**client._socket_for_reads(
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 113, in __enter**
>                           return next(self.gen)
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py",
>   line 1099, in _socket_for_reads
>                           server = topology.select_server(read_preference)
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py",
>   line 222, in select_server
>                           return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py",
>   line 182, in select_servers
>                           server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
>                         File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py",
>   line 198, in _select_servers_loop
>                           raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
>                       pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 192.168.1.100:27017: timed out

Answer (score 0):

Your connection looks a little misconfigured. Firstly you have half connection string, half parameter format. I'd suggest you stick with one or the other.

Your auth database is usually seperate to your actual databases (and it's usually called `admin`). Check this is correct.

There's no particular need to specify the authMechanism assuming you are using MongoDB 3.0 or later.

The connect=False is likely a red herring.

So I would try one of either:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:psw@192.168.1.100:27017/myappdb?authSource=admin')
```

or

```
client = MongoClient(host='192.168.1.100',
                     port=27017,
                     username='admin',
                     password='psw',
                     authSource='admin')
```

Comment: thank you for response. I don't think parsing is the problem and I tried anyway.I search and find this. [link](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe).maybe I should remove from docker and try it at local.

Comment: If you use the URL format it becomes easier to troubeshoot from the shell with `mongo mongodb://admin:psw@192.168.1.100:27017/myappdb?authSource=admin`